# how to install package from alpine aports

Tags: alpine-linux

I have been trying to install a package that exists in alpine aports 
and specifically [that](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/filebeat) one but I cannot find how. Is it even possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

The package `filebeat` you defined in the question is located in `edge` branch of `testing` repository. There is no such repo in alpine container by default.

In order to install a `filebeat` package on the alpine platform we need:

**1.** Add `testing` repo:

```
/ # echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/" >> /etc/apk/repositories
```

**2.** Install the `filebeat` package:

```
/ # apk add --no-cache filebeat
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: This apk-tools is OLD! Some packages might not function properly.
(1/1) Installing filebeat (5.6.3-r0)
Executing busybox-1.27.2-r7.trigger
OK: 20 MiB in 12 packages
```