# How to install filebet in docker alpine image?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, dockerfile, filebeat

Previously we were running filebeat on Amazon linux 2. Where i instlled it via command "yum install https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-oss-7.12.1-x86_64.rpm -y"

I did put this in my docker file.

> FROM eclipse-temurin:17.0.8.1_1-jdk-alpine
>
> WORKDIR /srv
>
> Install dependencies
> RUN apk --no-cache add 
> groff 
> less 
> jq 
> curl 
> rpm
>
> Install Filebeat
> RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates && 
> update-ca-certificates && 
> curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-oss-7.12.1-x86_64.rpm && 
> rpm -Uvh filebeat-oss-7.12.1-x86_64.rpm && 
> rm filebeat-oss-7.12.1-x86_64.rpm
>
> Copy local filebeat.yml into the Docker image
> COPY filebeat.yml /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
> RUN filebeat version
>
> COPY target/*.jar application/app.jar
>
> Start Filebeat and your Java application
> CMD ["sh", "-c", "filebeat -e -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml & java -jar app.jar"]

Here the filebeat version command is coming as not found

Comment: Alpine does not use yum or rpm files (that is CentOS / RedHat / Fedora / related distros). If you need to use alpine, the package manager is `apk`. It might be easier to use a base image that is derived from centos or fedora or another rpm-based image.

Comment: What would be command for that @jkr

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources that you can use to solve this: https://angrysysadmins.tech/index.php/2019/03/bailey/alpine-installing-filebeat/

[how to install package from alpine aports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257687/how-to-install-package-from-alpine-aports)